# Changing text in popup buttons (woodmart theme)

Tags: wordpress

Hello and thanks to the helpers,

I use the Woodmart template and there is a built-in option to create an age verification popup.
All the text is editable except the text of the buttons.

I want to change the buttons to:
I AM 21 OR OLDER
I AM UNDER 18

How can this be done?

Thanks again,

I tried to translate through WPML (I have a bilingual site) but it is not possible.
I tried to change the content file through the server but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the language file for this. Language files can be in the following directories:

/wp-content/languages/themes
/wp-content/themes/woodmart/languages/

If you want to get information about language files in Wordpress:

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/

You can use some applications that can edit .po files. After editing the .po files, you can restore the .po and .mo files to the corresponding directory.

There are also some plugins to do this from your wordpress admin panel. You can use them too.

You can also edit theme codes directly. This is generally not recommended because if you get an update it may break.

The files and lines with the relevant texts are:

/woodmart/inc/template-tags.php 143

/woodmart/inc/template-tags.php 147